# Forest: change depth of a sibling

Tags: diagrams, graphs, forest, trees

```
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [A[B[C]][D]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `A` has two children: `B` and `D`. I would like to place `D` just right of `C`. How do I control the depth of this node in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tier=<name>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [A[B[C,tier=bottom]][D, tier=bottom]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you want all leaves on the same level you can use a `for tree` with a conditional:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={if n children=0{tier=leaf}{}}
    [A[B[C]][D]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```